# Maven does not update/download SNAPSHOTS jars when executed with '-U,--update-snapshots' parameter

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I execute maven build with '`mvn clean deploy`' on a SNAPSHOT version of my, say, *dependency-lib*. The build was successful and the artifact got **successfully** deployed in the artifactory.

Then, I execute maven with arguments "`mvn -U clean package`" on my, say, *dependee-proj*, it does not download newest deployed version of *dependency-lib*. It just downloads the `maven-metadata.xml` from the artifactory and skips the downloading of the `jar` files. I verified the local maven repository, and there just some xmls got updated and no new updates of `jar` files.

Is it something wrong which i am doing?

PS: Deleting the *dependency-lib* worked but, somehow I feel that this is not a sane thing to do.

Comment: If you made an `mvn clean deploy` it will also install the artifacts into your local repository and there is no need to download them cause they are already on your local hard disk...

Comment: @khmarbaise Say, if the SNAPSHOT is built on a remote server (for eg. Jenkins), you won't have it locally

Comment: Are you using a repository manager?

Comment: Are your SNAPSHOTs really outdated after the `mvn -U clean package`. If your SNAPSHOTs are new, they are not downloaded again.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put an **updatePolicy** for the repository where you push your snapshots to. Ideally this is how snapshots are updated and later pulled by maven.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>you-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://host/repos/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Infact you can also do `mvn -U, --update-snapshots`

Comment: After this you have to do `mvn install -U`

Answer (score 0):

Maven is made up of phases. These [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) are:

- `validate` - validate the project is correct and all necessary
  information is available
- `compile` - compile the source code of the project
- `test` - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing
  framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or
  deployed
- `package` - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable
  format, such as a JAR.
- `verify` - run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure
  quality criteria are met
- `install` - install the package into the local repository, for use as a
  dependency in other projects locally
- `deploy` - done in the build environment, copies the final package to
  the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

Since `deploy` phase is the executed last, it means that before it **all preceding phases have been executed**, including the `install` phase which installs the artifact on your local repository.

So when `deploy` finishes, your local repository and remote have the latest version that you just uploaded so there is no need to download the latest version from the remote since it is already present on your local repository.

> Is it something wrong which i am doing?

Finally, to answer this, nothing strange is happening, just the normal behavior.

Deleting the artifact from the local repository of course forces maven to download the artifact from the remote, since that's the way maven works.

Comment: What if one team is developing the 'dependency' and another team the 'dependee'. Say, mvn clean deploy was executed in Jenkins, and I, as a dependee, execute the project locally, in which case i do not have the latest version of dependency in my repo unless maven force downloads the jars, which it doesn't - thats my experience

Comment: That's another question. It depends on which codebase you will deploy, which version you are deploying etc. Normally, if an artifact is developed by more than one team, you should rely on versioning. If you use the same version and the code base has changed, artifact will have different hash and when metadata is checked, maven will detect that artifact has changed and will redownload it.